# Drag and Drop UWP (Получение массива с путями на файлы)

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-n-drop

Есть дропзона в приложении. *Цель* такова: при переносе файла(ов) в дропзону, я должен получить на выходе массив с полными путями на файлы, которые были перетянуты в дропзону.

**Дропзона** представляет собой сетку:

***XAML***

```
<Grid x:Name="DropZone" Style="{StaticResource DropZoneStyle}"
              DragOver="DropZone_DragOver"
              AllowDrop="True"
              Drop="DropZone_Drop">
            
            <TextBlock Name="DropZone_txt"  
                       Text="Перетащите свои файлы сюда..." 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="40"/>
            
            <ComboBox Name="ImgExtension" Margin="62,-60,0,0" Width="128" >
                <TextBlock Text="PNG"/>
            </ComboBox>
            
        </Grid>
```

А здесь моя кривая реализация обработчика дропзоны:

***C#***

```
public List<string> Paths = new List<string>();

private async void DropZone_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            var images = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();

            if (images.Any())
            {
                StorageFile storageFile = images[0] as StorageFile;
                string name = storageFile.Name;
                Paths.Add(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

В данной реализации можно перетянуть только по одному файлику и, соответственно, в список добавляется только один путь к одному файлу. Прошу помочь исправить мой код

Comment: `StorageFile storageFile = images[0] as StorageFile;` ?

Comment: Не понял вашего вопроса. Что-то не так?

Comment: Я вам указал на конкретный код, где вы берёте один файл из списка. Если будете брать все файлы, а не один, может и решите свою задачу.